# Why does $p(a)=0$ imply $(x-a) \mid p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

There's something I've never understood about polynomials.

Suppose $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is a real polynomial. Then obviously,

$$(x-a) \mid p(x)\, \longrightarrow\, p(a) = 0.$$

The converse of this statement was used throughout high school, but I never really understood why it was true. I think *maybe* a proof was given in 3rd year university algebra, but obviously it went over my head at the time. So anyway:

> **Question.** Why does $p(a)=0$ imply $(x-a) \mid p(x)$?

I'd especially appreciate an answer from a commutative algebra perspective.

Comment: You know, this does not work for polynomials over non-commutative rings. It is a commutative algebra thing.

Comment: @orangeskid, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also understand division by $(x-a)$ as follows:

Take a polynomial

$$P(x) = \sum c_k x^k$$

Plug in $x+a$ instead of $x$. You get a new polynomial in $x$, $P(x+a) = \sum_k c_k (x+a)^k = \sum_k d_k x^k$
that is
$$P(x+a) = \sum d_k x^k$$

Now in the last equality instead of $x$ plug in $x-a$. You get

$$P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n d_k (x-a)^k$$

This is important, you can expand $P(x)$ as a sum of powers of $(x-a)$. Now if you plug in the value $x=a$ above you get

$$P(a) = d_0$$

since all the other terms are $0$. So what you have is

$$P(x) = d_0 + (\sum_{k\ge 1} d_k (x-a)^k) = P(a) + (x-a) \cdot (\sum_{k\ge 1} d_k (x-a)^{k-1})$$

Here is your division by $(x-a)$.

Now you see: if $P(a) =0$ then $P(x)$ is indeed divisible by $(x-a)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: *using Division Algorithm*, you have:
$$p(x)=(x-a)q(x)+r $$ 
$$0=p(a)=r$$

---

Edition: (by comment of Marc van Leeuwen). definition from "*Cox D., Little J., O'Shea D. Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* "
[image]

Comment: I think one should add that the division algorithm ensures that the remainder satisfies $\deg(r)<\deg(x-a)=1$ so that $r$ is a constant polynomial, which can then be identified with the number $p[a]$.

Comment: thank you  @Marc van Leeuwen. my answer was in fact a **Hint**, as you see. but I edited it based on your comment.

Comment: $x-a$  is the $g$ in the proposition and $deg (r) \lt deg (x-a)=1$ so $r$ is a constant as  *@Marc van Leeuwen* says.

Comment: @user1, okay thanks for clarifying.

Comment: youare welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The proof using the division algorithm is a good one. Here is a more direct approach.

Note that $x^r-a^r=(x-a)(x^{r-1}+ax^{r-2}+a^2x^{r-3} \dots +a^{r-1})=(x-a)p_r(x)$ where $(x-a)$ is a factor.

Let $p(x)=c_rx^r+c_{r-1}x^{r-1}+\dots +c_0$. We are given $p(a)=0$ so $$p(x)=p(x)-p(a)=c_r(x^r-a^r)+c_{r-1}(x^{r-1}-a^{r-1})+\dots+c_0-c_0=(x-a)\left(c_rp_r(x)+c_{r-1}p_{r-1}(x)+\dots+c_1\right)$$

Comment: This is very cool.

Comment: Doesn't this work in $R[x]$ for *any* commutative ring $R$? **Edit.** Oh I see. We need $a$ to be unit, right?

Comment: @goblin: Yes, it does work. Good point!

Answer (score 1):

if $(x-a)$ does not divide $p(x)$, then every linear factor of $p(x)$ is not equal to $x-a$, that is, $p(a)$ is product of nonzero (complex) numbers, therefore $p(a) \neq 0$

Comment: Why does $p(x)$ have linear factors?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what helped make this intuitive for me when I took undergraduate abstract algebra:

You can always *try* to divide a polynomial by another polynomial. There is a division algorithm.

Of course, the division might not come out evenly, and there might be a remainder. But what would that remainder look like?