# Polynomial rings, division algorithm: $\, x^m-1\bmod x^n-1$

Tags: polynomials

Let $m,n$ be non-negative integers and $m>n$. Find polynomials $g(x),r(x)$ from the ring $R[x]$ such that $x^m -1 =q(x)(x^n-1) + r(x)$ , $r(x)=0$ or $\deg(r(x))<n$. In which case $x^n -1|x^m - 1$?

Comment: as an answer to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105056/why-does-pa-0-imply-x-a-mid-p/1105058#1105058) question i suggested a reference to "*Division $Algorithm$*. though i think Bill Dubuque has a complete answer(+1), but maybe a reference can help you too.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\,\ x^{\Large n}\!-1\!:\ x^{\Large n}\equiv 1,\ \ so\ \ x^{\Large m}\!-1 \equiv x^{\Large m\ mod\ n}\!-1 \equiv 0 \!\iff\! m\ mod\ n = 0 \!\iff\! n\mid m$

**Remark** $\ $ One can go further. The polynomial sequence $\rm\ f_n = (x^n-1)/(x-1),\, $ jut like the Fibonacci sequence, is a strong [divisibility sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence), i.e. $\rm\: (f_m,f_n)\: =\: f_{\:(m,n)}.\,$  The proof is simple - essentially the same as the proof of the Bezout identity for integers - see [my post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1/7479#7479).  We can view the polynomial Bezout identity as a q-analog of the integer Bezout identity, e.g. let's compare the Bezout identity for the gcd $\rm\ \color{#c00}3 = (\color{#0a0}{15},\color{blue}{21})\ $ in polynomial and integer form:

$$\rm\displaystyle \color{#c00}{\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}}\ =\ (x^{15} + x^9 + 1)\ \color{#0a0}{\frac{x^{15}-1}{x-1}}\ -\ (x^9+x^3)\ \color{blue}{\frac{x^{21}-1}{x-1}}$$

for  $\rm\ x = 1\ $ this specializes to  $\  \color{#c00}3\ =\ (3)\ \color{#0a0}{15}\ -\ (2)\ \color{blue}{21},\, $ the integer Bezout identity for the gcd.

It is well-worth studying these binomial divisibility properties since they occur quite frequently in number theoretical applications. Moreover, they provide excellent motivation for the more general study of divisibility theory, $ $ esp. in *divisor theory* form. For an introduction see Borovich and Shafarevich: [Number Theory.](http://books.google.com/books?id=njgVUjjO-EAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=borevich+shafarevich&source=bl&ots=cjb4-Yjxs4&sig=BO5QyJVHF0LHqiCw_zkU4mVInQ8&hl=en&ei=KbGKTbu6Gc7Atgext7DrDQ)